# Has happened for the first time since/that our family has gone on vacation

Tags: determiners

> 1. It has happened for the first time in 4 years **since** our family has gone on vacation.

> 2. It has happened for the first time in 4 years **that** our family has gone on vacation.

I’m really confused between these sentences since #1 might be a usual construction, but it kind of sounds wrong to me in this case. I would rather use #2 in this situation. Am I correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) is definitely not a usual construction. For one thing, *it's* is short for *it is* or *it has*, so we never say *it's has.*

If you have had your first family vacation in four years, use sentence (2) (but with *It has*).

If the family has *not* had a vacation in the last four years, say *It's four years since our family has had a vacation.*

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was not supposed to write “it’s has”; #1 was a typo and it happened to be that I copied #1 and pasted it, so #2 automatically became incorrect. Anyways great answer :-).